# Как правильно скрыть часть изображения?

Tags: html, css, css3, svg, inkscape

Имеется изображение в формате `<img src="/">`, как скрыть обрезать угол изображения?

А если изображение будете задано в качестве `bg` фона?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: а вас, что-ли любая форма обрезки устроит? Может образец приложите как вам нужно?

Comment: @Alexandr_TT Приложил изображение, нужно угол у изображения срезать...

Comment: то есть нужно просто принцип, форма обрезки не важна?

Comment: да, про `overflow: hidden;` знаю )

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Решение SVG

С помощью техники,- использование `mask svg`,  можно сделать очень сложные вырезы, которые трудно повторить в `css`

Для этого понадобится минимальные навыки работы в векторном редакторе.

- Загружаем нужную картинку в векторный редактор (`Inkscape`) и рисуем `path` который будет служить границей вырезанной части.

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Рисуем кривую с помощью инструмента -

  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
- Далее в меню `Inkscape` выбираем <kbd>Контур</kbd> / оконтурить
  обводку
- Сохраняем файл SVG и в любом текстовом редакторе копируем из файла формулу кривой

  ```
  <path d="m1501.0981 531.97843c0 0-136.8524-9.46102-176.9284 35.38568-34.0435 
  38.09613 4.578 104.75892-13.0368 152.71718-24.375 66.3636-135.9556 121.05631-
  135.9556 121.05631L1500 843Z" id="path3338" style="fill:none;stroke:#000"/>
  ```

Вот эта кривая линия и будет границей вырезания части изображения.

Ниже код с маской:

```html
<style>
    .container {
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        background:grey;
        background-size:cover;
        background-position: 0% 100%;
    }
</style>
<div class="container">
    <svg version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" width="100%" height="100%" viewBox="0 0 1500 843" preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin meet" >
        <defs>
            <mask id="cat" > 
                <rect width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
                <path d="m1501.0981 531.97843c0 0-136.8524-9.46102-176.9284 35.38568-34.0435 38.09613 4.578 104.75892-13.0368 152.71718-24.375 66.3636-135.9556 121.05631-135.9556 121.05631L1500 843Z" id="path3338" style="fill:black;stroke:#000"/>
            </mask>
        </defs>
        <image xlink:href="https://i.stack.imgur.com/styoZ.jpg" width="100%" height="100%" mask="url(#cat)" />
    </svg>
</div>
```

Comment: Вот эта инструкция, великолепно! =)

Answer (score 4):

```css
body {
  background: linear-gradient(to right, blue, red);
  padding: 0 20%;
}

section, div {
  overflow: hidden;
}

div {
  padding-top: 100%;
  margin-top: -100%;
  transform: skew(0deg, -10deg);
}

img {
  display: block;
  max-width: 100%;
  transform: skew(0deg, 10deg);
}
```

```html
<section>
  <div>
    <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/styoZ.jpg">
  </div>
</section>
```

Comment: замечательно!  Смотрится великолепно, особенно тему с градиентами хорошо использовал.От всей души (+)

Answer (score 3):

Вам может подойти свойство `mask-image`

Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/fbB3P/254/

Документация: https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/CSS/mask-image

Поддержка    браузерами: https://caniuse.com/#search=mask-image

Comment: Получилось. Благодарю!

Answer (score 2):

Я бы пошел путем наименьшего сопротивления и просто отредактировал изображение с созданием **прозрачного слоя**.(Тут нужно отказаться от формата jpg)

Comment: Это самый простой способ, но в моем случае не рабочий...

Answer (score 0):

Если правильно вас понял. То в этом случае, лучше img обернуть в div и div-блоку задать размеры width и height меньшие, чем у img и добавить свойство для div overflow: hidden. Например:
Размеры img (width: 300px, height: 300px)
Делаем:

```
<div style="width: 250px; height: 250px; overflow: hidden;">
  <img src="/" width="300" height="300" />
</div>
```

Изображение обрежется на 50px справа и снизу.

Для фона тоже самое.

Comment: Для обрезки угла в div необходимо добавить псевдокласс :after

Comment: про `overflow: hidden;` знаю, но это не совсем то. Нужно именно обрезать угол у изображения.

Comment: div:after {content: ''; position: absolute; right: 0; top: 0; background: transparent; display: block; width: 50px; heigth: 50px; z-index: 2} В данном случае обрежется правый верхний угол на 50px. И также не забываем добавлять для div {position: relative;} И также нужно указать z-index для псевдоэлемента

Comment: на `background` изображение работает?

Comment: для того чтобы добавить фон необходимо создать <div class="bg"></div> и добавить к нему стиль .bg {background: url('путь к картинке.формат_картинки') no-repeat 0 0}. Обрезка угла будет работать также как описано выше.

Comment: Опробовал с изображением и с фоном - не работает у меня. Большая просьба, отредактируйте пожалуйста ответ на вопрос с понятным видом кода html / css, а то в комментариях какая-то каша получилась...